# Как перезапустить thread group в JMeter?

Tags: java, jmeter

Мне необходимо отправить 500 запросов с round-up = 300 n-ое количество раз, при этом после завершения round-up необходимо выставить задержку в 1 минуту. Возможно ли это сделать в JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В зависимости от того, чего вы хотите добиться (остановить все потоки сразу или каждый из них независимо):

1. Чтобы остановить все потоки добавьте [Flow Control Action](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Flow_Control_Action) Sampler и сконфигурируйте его следующим образом

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   затем добавьте [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer/) и выставьте "Number of Simulated Users to Group by" равным `500`

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

   таким образом все виртуальные пользователи одновременно выполнят Flow Control Action Sampler и пойдут дальше
2. Чтобы остановить каждый поток на минуиу по-отдельности то же самое, только выключите или удалите Synchronizing Timer

Comment: Сделал все как вы написали, но после того как все запросы отправляются происходит задержка и сразу окончание теста. Мне же необходимо чтобы после этой задержки то же количество запросов отправилось с тем же раунд-апом, а после опять произошла задержка и т. д. n-ое количество раз, ну или до мануальной остановки теста.

Comment: В [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) -> `Loop Count` -> можно задать количество итераций. Если поставить галку `Infinite` или ввести `-1` тест будет длиться пока вы его не остановите

Comment: Кажется я немного разобрался. Спасибо.